# Format Negative numbers in parenthesis BUT NOT with $ symbol?

Tags: .net, vb.net, parentheses, negative-number

I have seen all over the internet to format a NEGATIVE double value with a parenthesis WITH a `$` symbol ie. currency type.

I am looking for a .NET format string, to format

```
12345.67 = 12,345.67

-12345.67 = (12,345.67)
```

Comment: VB.NET or C#? Title and tags disagree.

Comment: var ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

    if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DisplayName == ci.DisplayName)
    {
        ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
        ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    }

Answer (score 68):

MSDN on [conditional formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) to the rescue!

You can specify up to three different sections of your format string at once, separating them with semicolons. If you specify two format string sections, the first is used for positive and zero values while the second is used for negative values; if you use three sections, the first is used for positive values, the second for negative values, and the third for zero values.

The output from this C# code:

```
        string fmt1 = "#,##0.00";
        string fmt2 = "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)";
        double posAmount = 12345.67;
        double negAmount = -12345.67;
        Console.WriteLine("posAmount.ToString(fmt1) returns " + posAmount.ToString(fmt1));
        Console.WriteLine("negAmount.ToString(fmt1) returns " + negAmount.ToString(fmt1));
        Console.WriteLine("posAmount.ToString(fmt2) returns " + posAmount.ToString(fmt2));
        Console.WriteLine("negAmount.ToString(fmt2) returns " + negAmount.ToString(fmt2));
```

is:

```
posAmount.ToString(fmt1) returns 12,345.67
negAmount.ToString(fmt1) returns -12,345.67
posAmount.ToString(fmt2) returns 12,345.67
negAmount.ToString(fmt2) returns (12,345.67)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the FormatNumber function:

`FormatNumber(-100, UseParensForNegativeNumbers:=TriState.True)`

will return "(100)"

There's more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfta99yt%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: This is in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace, so to use it in C# you need to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic first.

Comment: Thanks Jon! Appreciate your quick answer!

Comment: Another reason (as if I needed more) why VB rules :-) Managed to add one line of code and a checkbox to now run reports either with a minus sign or in brackets